# What does the 있나 싶어요 sentence ending mean?

Tags: sentence-endings

I came across this sentence today:

> 회사에서 별도로 교육을 할 필요가 있나 싶어요.

I am most confused by the ending. What does 있나 싶어요 here imply?

Answer (score 4):

`...나 싶다` is used when the main verb is guessed by the speaker.

For instance, if the person went out thinking the guests were coming, they might say:

> 손님들이 오나 싶어서, 밖에 나가 봤어요

To express "I felt as if I were never that way":

> 내가 언제 그랬나 싶었어

It's common to think "If you have seen one, you think you may know them all":

> 하나를 보면 전체를 알 수 있지 않나 싶다

---

In the case from your office, the person is asking if training is necessary:

> 교육을 할 필요가 있나요?

They add the increased supposition with `있나 싶어`

> Do we really need separate training in the office?

Comment: Extra thanks for all the examples!